# Sqoop export from Hcatalog to MySQL with different col names assign

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, hcatalog

Now my hive table with columns - `id, name`

and MySQL table - `number, id, name`

**I want to map `id (from hive)` with `number (from mysql)`, `name (from hive)` with `id (from mysql)`.**

I use the command :

```
  sqoop export --hcatalog-database <my_db> --hcatalog-table <my_table> --columns "number,id" \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://db...:3306/test \
  --username <my_user> --password <my_passwd> --table <my_mysql_table>
```

However, it didn't work.

The same scenario liked this case can work fine [1]. The requirement can be fulfilled by locating the hive table on hdfs and using the following command to achieve.

```
  sqoop export --export-dir /[hdfs_path] --columns "number,id" \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://db...:3306/test \
  --username <my_user> --password <my_passwd> --table <my_mysql_table>
```

Is there any solution can fulfill my scenario via Hcatalog?

reference :

[1]. [Sqoop export from hive to oracle with different col names, number of columns and order of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777209/sqoop-export-from-hive-to-oracle-with-different-col-names-number-of-columns-and)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't used the hcatalog part of sqoop, but as is written [in the manual](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal), the next script should do the work:

```
sqoop export --hcatalog-database <my_db> --hcatalog-table <my_table> --map-column-hive "number,id" \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://db...:3306/test \
  --username <my_user> --password <my_passwd> --table <my_mysql_table>
```

This option: `--map-column-hive` when is used along with `--hcatalog`, does the work for hcatalog instead of hive.

Hope that this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After I tried the argument --map-column-hive, it still got the ERROR : java.io.IOException: Caught Exception checking database column number in hcatalog table. 
This error the same as I used the argument --column

Comment: hm .. so your column in hcatalog table it's number ? -> "..checking database column **number** in hcatalog table" also, the structure from hive differs to the structure from hcatalog?

Comment: All columns in hcatalog and MySQL are setting as STRING type.